# How to run iOS simulator 4.3 in Xcode 4.6?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, simulator

I'm trying to test my iOS application on iOS 4.x.
I'm using MAC OS X Mountain Lion(10.8.2) and Xcode 4.6.
I tried to install the older iOS 4 version from the Downloads tab inside the Xcode but that simulator option is not available: http://cl.ly/image/412l3V3C1E3W

I then manually installed the the iOS 4.0 and 4.3 sdk using the packages from the `"xcode_4.0.2_and_ios_sdk_4.3.dmg" file and now they are available inside the folder: "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs".`

My deployment target is set to 4.0 and I'm able to select the iOS simulator from the scheme.

I even checked if the iOS 4.x SDK is correctly installed using the command line "xcodebuild -showsdks" and the system recognizes it:

```
$ xcodebuild -showsdks
OS X SDKs:
    Mac OS X 10.7                   -sdk macosx10.7
    OS X 10.8                       -sdk macosx10.8

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 4.3                         -sdk iphoneos4.3
    iOS 6.1                         -sdk iphoneos6.1

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 4.0             -sdk iphonesimulator4.0
    Simulator - iOS 4.3             -sdk iphonesimulator4.3
    Simulator - iOS 5.0             -sdk iphonesimulator5.0
    Simulator - iOS 5.1             -sdk iphonesimulator5.1
    Simulator - iOS 6.1             -sdk iphonesimulator6.1
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I run the project I get and error from the simulator: "iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled."

And if I try to change the version from the simulator there is no 4.3 option: 
http://cl.ly/image/1y04201e2o08

Does anyone know how to force the simulator to start with iOS 4.3?

Comment: There is one flag in xcode which check if its Mountain Lion then Simulator 4.3 is not available, it is available in Lion OS. But, YES, you can debug in iOS 4.3 devices. Hope this info helps you..

Comment: Where is is that flag? Can I do something that will let the simulator start with iOS 4.3 even in Mountain Lion? Maybe start it from the command line with a flag/parametter?

Comment: No, you cannot change that flag. I too tried same, but it's not possible.. :(

Comment: OK thank you PJ Then the last solution is to install a Lion virtual machine where I can install Xcode with iOS 4? Come on Apple... we should have access to any IOS version in the Simulator.

Comment: If you have Device with iOS 4.3, than you can use that too!

Comment: Debug functionality is present for iOS 4.3 devices.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have an iOS 4.3 device so I'm forced to find a way to test the project on the simulator. Do you know any hack to make the iOS4.3 version available on the simulator?

Comment: Check my answer <br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353099/run-app-using-xcode-4-6-in-ios-4-3-simulator/16353379#16353379