# run app using xcode 4.6 in ios 4.3 simulator

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4, ios-simulator, xcode4.6

I am actually trying to run my application in 4.3 simulator from xCode 4.6. I copy the sdk for simulator 4.3 at the path, it builds successfully but cant run the application in simulator. So now what can I do to solve the problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there any error gives in console.

Comment: no, it will displays an alert with message like "iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled."

Comment: 4.3 is simulator version or xCode version?

Comment: 4.3  is simulator version, my xcode version is 4.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Mac OS 10.7.x and have upgraded to Xcode 4.6, then you could have or download simulator 4.3 version. But, if you are using Mac OS 10.8.x, then you can not have simulator 4.3 version. The reason is 4.3 simulator on Mac OS 10.8.x crashed a lot, so Apple has removed that. 

 Check this link:- 
 http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/111568-what-happened-to-the-ios-4-3-simulator-in-xcode-4-6.html

Comment: yeah.... I am using MAC 10.8. Thank you. That means I never can have simulator version 4.3. :(

Comment: That's wrong. I have Mac OS 10.8.x, installed Xcode 4.4 and Xcode 4.5, using iOS 4.3 simulator. Works fine. Not sure about Xcode 4.6 though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and make sure the "Target SDK" you have selected in your project is in fact installed under the Downloads windows. For me this magically was uninstalled. Once i installed the SDK that my app was using, all worked again

**Also Check**

Xcode>Preferences> click Downloads tab. The supported simulators are in there.

Please try this and let me inform any problem still exists.

Comment: In the list on the components in the Download section, 4.3 is not available.

Comment: So First of all download the simulator 4.3

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components
2. There you can see the list of simulators (v4.3 also there). Click on install against the simulator that you want to install.
3. After Installation, restart Xcode
4. Go to the project info and set your build target to iOS Version 4.3

Now the simulator version 4.3 will be listed in your schema selector.

Cheers :)

**Note: If you are using Mac 10.8, you cannot have 4.3 simulator**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. yeah I get to know about that.

Comment: That's wrong. I have Mac OS 10.8.x, installed Xcode 4.4 and Xcode 4.5, using iOS 4.3 simulator. Works fine. Not sure about Xcode 4.6 though.